# Vue is not rendering on right tags component

Tags: vue.js

The way i am defining my props;

```
<template>
  <div>
    <vinput id="login_name" label="Phone number"></vinput>

            <div class="flex flex-col">
                <label for="email-phone">School slug</label>
                <input type="text" id="email-phone" class="border py-2 rounded">
            </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import vinput from '../../components/Input.vue'

export default {
  components:{
    vinput
  }
}
</script>
```

The way i am passing the props

```
<vinput id="login_name" label="Phone number"></vinput>
```

Please why is the browser rendering it this way:

```
<div class="mt-4">
<div class="flex flex-col" id="login_name" label="Phone number">
<label></label>
  <input type="tex" class="border py-2 rounded">
 </div>
<div class="flex flex-col"><label for="email-phone">School slug</label><input type="text" 
id="email-phone" class="border py-2 rounded"></div></div>
```

I was expecting interpolation in the label and input not in the div

====Edited====
vinput component

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <label :for="id">{{ label }}</label>
    <input :type="type ? type : 'tex'" 
    :class="classes ? classes :''" class="border py-2 rounded"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      props:['label', 'id','type', 'classes']
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please share the code of `vinput` component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `props:['label', 'id','type', 'classes']` away from `data`.

Those are totally different things.

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ['label', 'id','type', 'classes'],
  data(){
    return {};
  },
};
</script>
```